# Need Access to API Endpoint to register but it returns that needs access the JWT (MalformedJwtException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Controller:

```
@RestController @RequestMapping("/users") public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService service;
    @PostMapping
    public void postUser(@RequestBody User user){
        service.createUser(user);
    } }
```

Configuration class:

```
  public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    private static final String[] SWAGGER_WHITELIST = {
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**"
    };
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("Configure");
        
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .addFilterAfter(new JWTFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(SWAGGER_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users").permitAll() 
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/users").hasAnyRole("USERS","MANAGERS")
                .antMatchers("/managers").hasAnyRole("MANAGERS")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

> Postman returns:  403 Forbidden

Console exception:

> io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: JWT strings must contain
> exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0     at
> io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:235)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a rule to permit register endpoint like this

```
.antMatchers("${/register-end-point}").permitAll()
```

for the given controller add this rule

```
.antMatchers("/users").permitAll()
```